# iPhone console for nslog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nslog

How can i see nslog messages when I am testing on device? My only way right now is to have a UITextView and put message in there, there must be a better way..Thanks.

I went to seetings and turned on console but still don't know how to see them. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: You mean if you are not connected to your Mac (then you have View/Navigatros/Log or CMD+Shift+Y) and you don't want to fiddle with Organizer afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These calls will output to your devices system log.  You'll be able to get these from the XCode Organizer when you plug your phone back in.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a few apps you can install from App Store on your device (search for free ones, with Console in their title, and ability to send emails with logs).

This is useful especially if you want to debug some errors on your beta testers devices, or don't want to connect your device every time you want to see what's in the console log.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. will check those out.