# iphone app memory management in save/restore

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am confused by the memory management in this scenario.
In my app user makes periodic input inside UITextField tf and the typed strings (NSString*) are stored as elements of a MSMutableArray *arr through addObject.  The stored collection is displayed inside a UITableView. My app can go into bkgr and is periodically awakened by push notifications.  As I understand it, the data stored in arr can be lost while my app is non-active and, to preserve it, I need to do archive/restore. 
My archive/restore are using

```
NSUserDefaults*prefs;  
[prefs setObjectForKey:x forKey:key]
```

to archive and

```
[prefs objectForKey:key]
```

to restore every item of arr.

Question1: I think that to prevent the memory leak I need to do [arr release]
Do I also need to do a release on every  object which I have added to arr or, since I did not allocate the NSString for tf, it will be done for me automatically?

Question2: in restore I start with something like arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil]; before I can read and add archived items back to arr. I think that [prefs objectForKey:key] is released as soon as I leave the scope in which it was read - thus I need something like retain to keep it in arr. Would this schema work in the next archive/restore cycle due to another app deep sleep?
Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same?
Thanks.
Victor

Comment: It would be great to see more code examples in the question. It's a little confusing to understand the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding objects to an NSArray causes the NSArray to retain each object.

So in a case where you are instantiating objects, then adding them to an array, those objects do not need to be further retained:

```
// saving strings inside an array, then array to the NSUserDefaults
NSString *string1 = @"My String 1";
NSString *string2 = @"My String 1";
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
[arr addObject:string1];
[arr addObject:string2];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];;  
[prefs setObject:arr forKey:@"MyArray"];

[arr release];
```

Then to restore the entire array from prefs:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSArray *array = [prefs objectForKey:@"MyArray"];
```

Alternately, to save strings under separate keys, it would be something like this:

```
[prefs setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"MyFirstStringKey"];
[prefs setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"MySecondStringKey"];
```

For the restore, you will also just add the items to the array, no retain required:

```
// assuming this time several keys added to an array
// also note using autoreleased version of array - much easier
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];;  
[arr addObject:[prefs objectForKey:@"MyFirstStringKey"]];
[arr addObject:[prefs objectForKey:@"MySecondStringKey"]];

// then assign arr or use it otherwise
```

Also easier still is to use a non-mutable array and instantiate the array with the list of objects you want to have on the array:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];;  
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[prefs objectForKey:@"MyFirstStringKey"], [prefs objectForKey:@"MySecondStringKey"], nil];
```

Comment: `NSString` *can* be saved to the `NSUserDefaults`.  Any object can.  Just not basic types like int/float/char/bool/etc, thats why those need to be wrapped in a `NSNumber`.  OP, make sure to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` after you set/modify a value.

Comment: Sorry not more clear -- what I meant is whether an Array of objects can all be stored in the NSUserDefaults under a single key (see above where I'm setting the array for the key @"MyArray").  I realize that single objects like strings can be saved under single keys.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood :).  in that case, Im pretty sure you can have an array associated with just 1 key.  NSArray/NSMutableArray both only allow objects as values, so there shouldnt be any issues storing an array as a single value for a key.  Ill have to try it out though as Im not100% sure either.

Comment: Hi Jess, not sure you are right - if I don't use retain when I leave the scope the items of the array seem to be messed up (probably memory is released and used for something else). I guess addObject does not do the "deep copy", just adds the ptr. Thanks, Victor

Comment: NSString's are immutable, so no deep copy is required, only a retain.  The whole NSMutableArray will get dealloc'd if it's not retained.  Perhaps that is the issue?  Make sure the array is retained by something.

Comment: See also : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW12

Comment: Hi Jess, I will try to debug today. Thank you very much for your help. Also I think that there is some rating system, I would like to grant you points for your explanations - how to do that? Also - when running on IPhone how can I get NSLog (or some log)? Is it stored somewhere? Or just ignored when running on the device? Thanks again. Regards, Victor

Comment: If you like my answer, you "up-vote" it by clicking the up arrow.  And if my response answers your question, you click the check.

Comment: For the NSLog question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540960/iphone-console-for-nslog